# exit(0) in c only works occasionally

Tags: c, shell, loops, exit

I am trying to implement my own shell,there are many things not working in it but for now i'm trying to solve the first error. 
When my shell is running and i enter exit as the first command,it works fine,however,when i enter exit as the second input i should write exit an extra time for it to exit my shell,if i enter it as the 3rd command,i have to enter it 2 extra times,and so on. 
Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

    int argumentsnum;
    int status;

    char *arguments[30];
    char *temp;
    int processes_count=0;

    printf("My Shell\n");
    while (1)
    {
        char input[60];

        printf("Enter command\n");
        while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Enter command \n");
        } /*end whileloop*/

        for (argumentsnum = 0; argumentsnum < 31; argumentsnum++)
        {
            temp = strtok(input, " \t\n");
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                arguments[argumentsnum] = temp;
            } /*endif*/

        } /*end forloop*/
        if (strcmp(arguments[0], "exit") == 0)
        {
            printf("Exiting shell\n");
            int i;
            For(i=0;i<processes_count;i++){
            exit(0);
          }
        } /*endif*/
        pid_t id = fork();
        processes_count++;
        if (id == -1)
        {
            perror("Grab your own fork :@ \n");
            exit(1);
        } /*endif*/
        else if (id == 0)
        {
            execvp(arguments[0], arguments);
        } /*endelse*/
        else
        {

            wait(&status);
        }
    } /*end while(1)*/

} /*endmain*/
```

Comment: please indent your code

Comment: You have a big problem with your `execvp` call, in that you don't terminate the array properly. The last entry must be a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: input is char 60, so your fgets should be one less to accomodate the trailing zero

Comment: You also have a potential buffer overflow, in that you loop 31 times for an array containing 30 entries.

Comment: @PeterMiehle The `fgets` function handles that automatically, if you pass the actual size of the array (as in the case of the OPs code).

Comment: You `fork()` your process for every line entered, so you have to exit as many processes by typing 'exit' as you wrote lines of input.

Comment: Though i wasn't quite convinced,i tried to create a counter and count all the processes,and whenever i try to exit,i made a loop to keep on exiting processes_count time. See my updated code,it did not work though. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So should i loop until the index before the end of my array argument so i leave the last index null?

Comment: See @john Kugelman's answer. Add an error message and an exit after the exec.

Comment: PS in english we always put a space after a comma `,`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
execvp(arguments[0], arguments);
```

You need to do something if this call fails. If `execvp` fails because you passed it a bad command, the child process will continue onward. That means the *child* will process the next command, rather than the *parent*. The parent will be stuck in its `wait()` call, waiting for the child to terminate.

```
execvp(arguments[0], arguments);
perror("execvp");
_Exit(1);
```

Comment: Thank you,it worked. I still have other kinds of error but i will try to solve them by myself first.